# How to cover the test.ts file in an Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In our Angular project there is a ./sr/test.ts file that loads all specs file to run under test with Karma and Jasmine :

```html
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    keys(): string[];
    <T>(id: string): T;
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting(), {
    teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }
}
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

And SonarQube tells us that the code is not covered by tests.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

File `/src/test.ts` does actually set up the Karma testing environment; **it is NOT to be tested**.

You should update your SonarQube config so that files in the top level `/src` are not tested, but only those in `/src/app`, or `/src/lib`, or wherever your code is placed in.